# Add multiple titles in SwiftUI NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm very new to Xcode and SwiftUI and I was wondering if anybody knows how to add multiple `navigationBarTitle` in SwiftUI such as the one I found in Apple news. I wanna be able to add my main title for the page but then also supply like a date. Would love any suggestions someone has thank you :)
[image]

Comment: Seems a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825965/swiftui-multiline-text-in-a-navigationview-title

Answer (score -1):

Navigation bar in SwiftUI can be customized. Use code like below:

```swift
        NavigationView { 
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Title").font(.largeTitle)
                            Text("Subtitle").font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

This will make the navigation bar show like this:
[image]